# Adding Select All checkbox in a new row after combining two tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have successfully implemented select all check box at the end of the row in case there is only one table to display. However in one of the tab I am combining two tables data and dividing them in two columns thus the number of rows are different in those two columns.

I am trying to figure out how to populate two different select all checkbox at the end of the rows in both columns.

I am populating tables dynamically using JS. Here is my code

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul id="betTypesTabs"></ul>
</div>
```

JS for populating the table data from two sources

```
function drawSelectionsForDoubles(table, events, indexes) {

    // Array of Horse Selections for every event
    var arrayOfSelections = [];
    $.each(indexes, function (i, index) {
        arrayOfSelections[i] = events[index].markets[0].selections;
    });

    // Max number of Selections
    var maxNumberOfSelections = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<arrayOfSelections.length; i++) {
        if (arrayOfSelections[i].length > maxNumberOfSelections) maxNumberOfSelections = arrayOfSelections[i].length;
    }

    // Going through all the selections in the horizontal manner
    for (var i=0; i<maxNumberOfSelections; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<arrayOfSelections.length; j++) {

            var currentHorse = arrayOfSelections[j][i];

            // If the horse exists
            if (currentHorse != null) {

                // If the horse is participating in Running Double bet
                $.each(currentHorse.prices, function(index, value) {
                    if (value.betTypeId == 108) {

                        // Adding the record
                        // First tds in the row
                        if (j == 0) {
                            var tr = createTr(table.id + '_' + i, "white");
                            $(tr).append(createTd(null, null, currentHorse.position, null));
                            $(tr).append(createTd(null, null, currentHorse.name, null));
                            var td = createTd(null, null, "",null);
                            td.appendChild(createInput(table.id + '_' + i + "_doubles_" + currentHorse.id, table.id + "_doubles_1", "checkbox", null));
                            $(tr).append(td);
                            $(table).append(tr);
                        }

                        // Second column
                        else {
                            tr = document.getElementById(table.id + '_' + i);
                            if (tr == null) {
                                var tr = createTr(table.id + '_' + i, "white");
                                $(table).append(tr);
                                var td = createTd(null, null, '', 3);
                                $(tr).append(td);
                            }
                            $(tr).append(createTd(null, null, currentHorse.position, null));
                            $(tr).append(createTd(null, null, currentHorse.name, null));
                            var td = createTd(null, null, "",null);
                            td.appendChild(createInput(table.id + '_' + i + "_doubles_" + currentHorse.id, table.id + "_doubles_2", "checkbox", null));
                            $(tr).append(td);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now since the rows in two columns are different I want to add an extra row after the table where I can add a checkbox which will select all the rows in the table.

Comment: please post the relevant code so it will be easy to find out the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question and only posting the necessary code. What I need is to add extra row with select all check box at the end of the table.